# PHP Iterate loop

Tags: php, loops

I am new to php and I am trying to get this to loop through additional LI's as long as at least 8 more exist I have tried and can't figure out the proper way to accomplish this.

```
    <?php $model->getFeaturedVehicles(24, 0, unserialize($vtype), unserialize($makes), $p1range, $p2range, $filters) ?>
<div id="slider">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <?php while ($unit = $model->iterate()): ?>
      <div class="feature-vehicle" align="center"><a href="<?php echo DIR_REL,'/inventory/',$unit->url ?>"><img src="http://images.idealer1.com/getimage/90/<?php echo $unit->previewvpid ?>.jpg" alt="<?php echo $unit->description ?>" /></a>
        <p><?php echo $unit->description ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
    </li>
    <li>loop through 8 more if at least 8 more exist</li>
    <li>loop through 8 more if at least 8 more exist</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us what `iterate` does.  If the loop isn't stopping/never starts, then there is likely a problem with what that method returns.

Answer (score 0):

If the API doesn't expose a way to count the total number of records (including to get an array of the remaining records and count that), you could use the [PHP output buffering functions](http://php.net/book.outcontrol) (`ob_start`, etc.) to cache the data inside a for loop (counting to 8) and only print the results if the `$i` count reached 8 or more.